# Get all Shots (table) related to a SessionId (table) where a third table named Results connects them through Result Id. using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, linq

I want to use the sessionId to get all the Shots related to that specific Session. In the database the Shots table has a foreign key to a table named Results. Results has a foreign key to the table Session and it's primary key is the sessionId.
The code below returns 0 and I have tried multiple Include etc but nothing works.

Anyone know how to solve this and return a list of Shots related to a specific Session?

````
public List<Shots> GetShotListFromSession(string sessionId)
        {
            List<Shots> shotslist = new List<Shots>();
            shotslist = _db.Shots.Where(x => x.Results.Session.Id == sessionId).ToList();
            
            return shotslist;
            
        }
    
    ```
[Picture of the relations in database[1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfQcW.png
````

Comment: post your entities

Comment: @sommmen Did you see this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfQcW.png) picture? It shows the entities right?

Comment: I did not because the formatting is messed up - generally we prefer code to be posted directly.

Comment: @sommmen Ok sorry, it's my first post

Comment: As stated before, make sure we can see your ER so that someone can help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can first select the desired Results and then use `.SelectMany()` to retrieve and combine all associated Shots.

```cs
List<Shots> shotslist = _db.Results
    .Where(r => r.Session.Id == sessionId)
    .SelectMany(r => r.Shots)
    .ToList();
```